# How to avoid repeated rows for same values in ManyToOne mapping - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity Store which can have a credential.
Credentials can be given by user or can have default value.
The user can choose to enter custom credential.

I have a ManyToOne mapping between Store (as owning side) and Credential.

**Store.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "storecredential_id")
private Credential storeCredential = new Credential("root","admin123",true);
```

**Credential.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "storecredential")
private List<Store> stores;
```

Problem is I want to have only one row for common credential.

But with this mapping, for every store I create one row for default credentials.

For example, If Store A and Store B have default credential(not user given) , I want to map them to same row.

I thought of having the value as null when default credentials are going to be used, but I''m not sure if its a good practise.

Are there any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Edit :
I believe you want to store the data this way, for example :

```
[
 {
   "Store":"A",
   "data":[
           {
             "user":"x",
             "password":"p"
           },
            {
             "user":"y",
             "password":"p"
            }
           ]
},
{
   "Store":"B",
   "data":[
           {
             "user":"x",
             "password":"p"
           },
           {
             "user":"y",
             "password":"p"
           }
         ]
 },
 {
   "Store":"C",
   "data":[
           {
             "user":"x",
             "password":"p"
           },
           {
             "user":"y",
             "password":"p"
            }
           ]
   }
  ]
```

Code :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "user",
    "password"
})
public class Credential {
    
    @JsonProperty("user")
    private String user;
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String password;
    
    @JsonProperty("user")
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("user")
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("password")
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    
}




import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "Store",
    "data"
})
public class Example {
    
    @JsonProperty("Store")
    private String store;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<Credential> data = null;
    
    @JsonProperty("Store")
    public String getStore() {
        return store;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("Store")
    public void setStore(String store) {
        this.store = store;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<Credential> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(List<Credential> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Problem is username is not a unique key. StoreA is one entity and StoreB is another. Store A can have "admin" as username and "admin123" as password, while StoreB can also have "admin" as username but with different password.